# Escaped characters in URL request parameters cause duplicate values

Tags: url, binding, parameters, request

I am binding parameters in a URL to a hashmap like this:
    ?myObjectWithMapInIt['theKeyString'].value=theValue

When I list the keyset of the hashmap, I get two values relating to each parameter e.g.:
    param name: keyString value: theValue
    param name: %27keyString%27 value: theValue

%27 is the URL excape code for single quote, "'", so I can see why I might get this INSTEAD of the ordinary parameter name as a entry in my map, though why both? The same happens with other escaped characters such as space.

For info, I am using Java with the Stripes framework though I don't think that's relevant, it's pretty standard binding of a request parameter to a variable in a backing bean (object with a HashMap in it).

Thanks!